# pkg-config on cygwin will not find the gsl package

Tags: linux, cygwin, path

I am trying to use the Cygwin method for re-learning C using 21st Century C book by Ben Klemens. I've installed Cygwin and have been using apt-cyg to install the packages mentioned in the book. The packages seem to install fine, I can call gcc, make, pkg-config, etc... but pkg-config can't seem to find anything. More specifically this cannot find anything:

```
$ pkg-config --libs gsl
$ pkg-config --cflags gsl
```

I've seen a couple questions that talk about changing the path. I've tried changing it to:

```
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=c:\\cygwin\\usr\\local\\lib\\pkgconfig
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=C:\\cygwin\\bin
```

I also already have all of this installed:

- binutils
- gcc
- gcc-core
- gcc-g++
- make
- gdb
- gsl

I verified they are installed using:

```
$ cygcheck -c | grep {string}
```

Admittedly, I'm not greatly familiar with Linux systems otherwise it'd be my main system and I'd not be using Cygwin ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was setting the wrong path, I thought the export command was adding paths to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH variable, obviously I needed to prefix with the variable at the beginning (just like I'm supposed to do in Windows :) and separate with a colon if I really wanted to add paths

```
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:{my_new_path}
```

But that wasn't the real problem of why pkg-config couldn't find gsl, even though I thought I installed the package, what I really needed to install was gsl-devel, and then it would add its .pc file to /lib/pkgconfig.

So to recap, I needed to use my package manager to install {package-name}-devel (gsl-devel), which would then add the relevant {package-name}.pc file (gsl.pc).

Set the variable correctly:

```
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/lib/pkgconfig
```

then get the development package:

```
$ apt-cyg install gsl-devel
```